# How to disable tabs in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, uinavigationbar

I am making a simple website using bootstrap and can't get the navigation bar to look the way I wan't it to. I am trying to get rid of the background color in the nav bar that appears when hovering over the navigation elements. Bootstrap seems to automatically generate this hover effect but I wan't to have a plane text only navigation bar. Is there a simple way that I can disable this hover-over effect using CSS or perhaps by using bootstrap classes differently? Have been stuck on this for a while now so hope someone can help me out on this.

Thanks in advance

```
<nav class="navbar-wrapper" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-right">
                                <li><a href="#">1</a><li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a><li>
                                <li><a href="#">3</a><li>
                                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                                <li class="navbarpadding">
                                    <form action="#">
                                        <button class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn">Apply</button>
                                    </form>
                                </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get rid of the hover effect by using this css code

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
background: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! Was thinking way to complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you right click and inspect element you can copy the css path.

Using that you can remove the background with this code.

```
  body > nav > div > div.collapse.navbar-collapse.navbar-ex1-collapse > div > ul > li > a
  {
      background:none;
  }
```